# Unable to get value from list inorder to set Grid header value c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, converters, gridviewheader

I am trying to set grid header value from list getting error

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

I check it first but I am converting list value to string and while debugging I can find value in list

code is given below,

```
        List<string> rows = new List<string>(
new string[] { "Item", "Quantity", "Price" });

                GdItemList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = Convert.ToString(rows[0]);
                GdItemList.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = rows[1].ToString();
                GdItemList.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = rows[2].ToString();
```

GdItemList Grid view is like ,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GdItemList" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CellPadding="4"
                    EmptyDataText="No Record Found" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> rows = new List<string>(
    new string[] { "Item", "Quantity", "Price" });

GdItemList.Columns[0].HeaderText = Convert.ToString(rows[0]);
GdItemList.Columns[1].HeaderText = rows[1].ToString();
GdItemList.Columns[2].HeaderText = rows[2].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your List of strings but with your GdItemList.
There is no error in the code you have shown us: https://repl.it/Njj3/0

Comment: I guess the header row or even the whole "GdItemList" is not initialized?

Comment: That may be the problem. Something in the GridView is not initialized. We need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the ElementAt function? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx

```
List<string> rows = new List<string>(new string[] { "Item", "Quantity","Price"});

GdItemList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = rows.ElementAt(0);
```

Comment: I think [Imran Ali Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2723943/imran-ali-khan)'s answer is the correct one here.

Comment: i tried it is giving same error Object reference not found to an instance of an object.